# Why am I getting no value after I clicked button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array-map

I set the value for the array of images as "". Whenever I move one of these 4 images and I clicked the button. I expect to return a new array to get one of four images' information such as src, x, and y coordinate. Instead, I get blank in the array.

```
this.state = {
  title: this.props.title || '',
  images: [{
    image: this.props.image || "",
    x: this.props.x || "",
    y: this.props.y || ""
  }],
}

handleSubmit = () => {
let getImagesList = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'));

console.log(getImagesList);

getImagesList.map(data => {
  if(data.dataset.x > 0) {

    console.log(data);

    var arr = [{
      image: data.src,
      x: data.dataset.x,
      y: data.dataset.y
    }]
    this.setState({
      images: this.state.images.concat(arr)
    })

    console.log("successfully added");
    console.log(this.state.images)
  }

return (
  <div className="Wrapper"> 
    <div className="overallshapes">
      <div className="select_image">
        {image_url}
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
        Save
      </button>
      <button onClick={this.props.onFormClose}>
        Cancel
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

I expect the output of after I first click the button [image: The actual output] but the actual output is none in these array after I first clicked the button. [image]

Comment: is result logging from this line `console.log(this.state.images)`?

Comment: @MaheerAli, yes, this `console.log(this.state.images)` is the result after I inserted new value in setState.

Comment: can you please give codepen.

Answer (score 1):

A thing to consider in above code is that setState function is asynchronous. It isn't necessary that console.log will print the value of images you assigned in setState method, unless you use the following syntax:

```
`this.setState({
  images: this.state.images.concat(arr)
}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.images);
})
```

`

It can be printing old values of state on your console.